# Run Macro from value change and check box

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code working that will, when a check box is marked, do the following: unhide "travel calculator" sheet, unlocked the current sheet, change the value of cells based on cells from the "travel calculator" sheet, then lock the current sheet again. When it the check box is not marked, the cells should remain unlocked and the "travel calculator" should remain hidden. This is great, however, I would like it to be constantly updating the value in the current sheet based on changes made to the travel calculator when the check box is marked (Value=True).

Does anyone have any changes to the code below that I could try to make it update when the box value = True AND the value of the travel total from the "travel calculator" sheet changes?
Thanks!

```
Private Sub travelcalc_Click()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    If Me.travelcalc.Value = False Then
    Range("C19:L20").Locked = False
    Sheets("Travel Calculator").Visible = False
Else
    Sheets("Travel Calculator").Visible = True
    Range("$C$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$N$14")
    Range("$D$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$P$14")
    Range("$E$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$R$14")
    Range("$F$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$T$14")
    Range("$G$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$V$14")
    Range("$H$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$X$14")
    Range("$I$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$Z$14")
    Range("$J$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AB$14")
    Range("$K$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AD$14")
    Range("$L$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AF$14")
    Range("$C$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$N$29")
    Range("$D$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$P$29")
    Range("$E$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$R$29")
    Range("$F$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$T$29")
    Range("$G$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$V$29")
    Range("$H$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$X$29")
    Range("$I$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$Z$29")
    Range("$J$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AB$29")
    Range("$K$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AD$29")
    Range("$L$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AF$29")
    Range("C19:L20").Locked = True
End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password", AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the following code to the Travel Calculator worksheet.  It will evaluate if a change has been made to the total value each time you move a cell in the travel Calculator sheet and the travelcalc box is checked and updated if necessary.  It will also update as soon as you deactivate the sheet if the travelcalc box is checked.

```
Public originalTotalValue As Currency

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
origionalTotalValue = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("Your Travel Value").Value

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
If Me.travelcalc.Value = True Then
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$C$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$N$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$D$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$P$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$E$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$R$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$F$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$T$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$G$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$V$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$H$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$X$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$I$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$Z$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$J$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AB$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$K$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AD$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$L$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AF$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$C$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$N$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$D$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$P$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$E$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$R$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$F$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$T$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$G$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$V$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$H$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$X$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$I$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$Z$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$J$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AB$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$K$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AD$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$L$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AF$29")
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim updatedTotalValue As Currency
updatedTotalValue = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("Your Travel Value").Value
If Me.travelcalc.Value = True And originalTotalValue <> updatedTotalValue Then
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$C$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$N$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$D$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$P$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$E$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$R$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$F$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$T$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$G$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$V$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$H$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$X$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$I$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$Z$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$J$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AB$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$K$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AD$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$L$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AF$14")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$C$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$N$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$D$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$P$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$E$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$R$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$F$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$T$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$G$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$V$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$H$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$X$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$I$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$Z$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$J$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AB$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$K$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AD$29")
    Worksheets("Sheet Where Original Range is Located").Range("$L$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AF$29")
    origionalTotalValue = updatedTotalValue
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: daytonrazorback, thanks for your response! I like the idea of that. The issue with this solution is that cells from other sheets are pulling from this sheet as well. This is a large budget that many people will try to hit and exact number number by updating travel. So if it only runs once it is activated, then the sum of the budget won't update either unless the user goes from direct costs, to travel, then back to direct costs, then to the page. Ideally, I would incorporate a change value in that would run only if Me.travelcalc.Value = True

Comment: NU2this,  thanks for the additional information.  I have edited my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: daytonrazorback, Thank you! This had some bugs in it but I was able to modify a bit to make it work. The bad part is that has now triggered another issue that is perhaps for a  different question on here. Now, when I enter a value into the direct cost sheet (the sheet with the original range) the number is entered then I am taken to a different sheet automatically. I can't find any code in the workbook that would cause this.

Answer (score 0):

here is what the code looks like with my modifications. This bit of the code seems to be working very well. Thanks for the help!

```
Private Sub travelcalc_Click()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    If Me.travelcalc.Value = False Then
    Range("C19:L20").Locked = False
    Sheets("Travel Calculator").Visible = False
Else
    Sheets("Travel Calculator").Visible = True
    Range("$C$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$N$14")
    Range("$D$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$P$14")
    Range("$E$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$R$14")
    Range("$F$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$T$14")
    Range("$G$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$V$14")
    Range("$H$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$X$14")
    Range("$I$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$Z$14")
    Range("$J$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AB$14")
    Range("$K$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AD$14")
    Range("$L$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AF$14")
    Range("$C$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$N$29")
    Range("$D$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$P$29")
    Range("$E$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$R$29")
    Range("$F$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$T$29")
    Range("$G$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$V$29")
    Range("$H$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$X$29")
    Range("$I$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$Z$29")
    Range("$J$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AB$29")
    Range("$K$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AD$29")
    Range("$L$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AF$29")
    Range("C19:L20").Locked = True
End If
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password", AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True

End Sub

'the code below is entered into the travel sheet
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Worksheets("Direct Costs").Unprotect Password:="password"
Dim updatedTotalValue As Currency
Static oldval
    If Range("AG32").Value <> oldval Then
    oldval = Range("AG32").Value
    If Range("AL2").Value = True Then
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("C19:L20").Locked = False
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$C$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$N$14")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$D$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$P$14")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$E$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$R$14")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$F$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$T$14")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$G$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$V$14")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$H$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$X$14")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$I$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$Z$14")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$J$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AB$14")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$K$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AD$14")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$L$19") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AF$14")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$C$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$N$29")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$D$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$P$29")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$E$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$R$29")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$F$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$T$29")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$G$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$V$29")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$H$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$X$29")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$I$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$Z$29")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$J$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AB$29")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$K$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AD$29")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("$L$20") = Worksheets("Travel Calculator").Range("$AF$29")
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Range("C19:L20").Locked = True
End If
End If
    Worksheets("Direct Costs").Protect Password:="password", AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
End Sub
```